# Why does this code not let me just check for an invalid input

Tags: python-3.x

This is not the whole code but the code I am experimenting with to get a solution for the whole code. I also need an answer for dealing with invalid string inputs.

```
    def menu_payment():
burger_count= (input("Please input the number of Racquet Burgers (Cheese Burgers) you would like: "))
if (burger_count !=int) or (burger_count<=0):
    print("You must eneter a positive whole number for your order. Please try again.")
    menu_payment()
```

Comment: Hi, how are you today?: good
Please input the number of Racquet Burgers (Cheese Burgers) you would like: 1
You must eneter a positive whole number for your order. Please try again.
Please input the number of Racquet Burgers (Cheese Burgers) you would like:

Comment: That happened when I ran the code

Comment: Sorry for no spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
def menu_payment():
    burger_count = input("How many burgers would you like:")
    try:
        burger_count = int(burger_count)
        valid_number = 1
    except:
        print(burger_count, " is not a valid number")
        valid_number = 0
    if valid_number == 1 and burger_count > 0:
        print ("I will get your burgers right away")
    else: 
        print("Please put a valid number and no negetives")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This response really helped. Thanks again. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with checking for a valid string is coming from your if statement. I would suggest first, checking if the value is an int, then check the value for it. That is the easiest and least confusing way to fix that issue.

Comment: I see what your saying. Therefore, I implemented something to do that and put an else statement, but now no matter what I enter it tells me my input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Input will always convert the user input to string. Therefore, entering "1" is the string of "1", not the integer.

You could try wrapping your input with an int function like:

```
burger_count = int(input("Please input the number of Racquet Burgers (Cheese Burgers) you would like: "))
```

However, this would throw a ValueError if anything other than an integer is entered.

Also, I don't think checking the variable type works like that. You can do something like:

```
if type(burger_count) is not int:
    <do something>
```

Probably super inefficient (pre coffee scripting is bad) but here's how I would handle this:

```
def menu_payment():
    while True:
        try:
            burger_count = int(input("burgers: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("You must eneter a number for your order. Please try again.")
            continue
        else:
            if burger_count <= 0:
                print("You must eneter a number for your order. Please try again.")
                continue
            else:
                return burger_count
```